# CSS show indicator that line wrapped

Tags: html, css

Is it possible in CSS to show an indication that a line wrapped. For example, I have the the following in a "pre" block:

```
<html><body>Hello World</body></html>
```

I set white-space to pre-wrap so it won't cause left-right scroll issues. It works fine. It shows up something like:

```
<html><body>Hello World</body>
</html>
```

But, I want some indication that the line wrapped. Something like:

```
<html><body>Hello World</body>
| </html>
```

Then, I can tell the reader that the | means the line wrapped. So, treat it as a single line of text. This will also be very useful if it breaks in the middle of something where a line wrap is terrible, such as:

```
form.getSubmit().style.background
Color = 'green';
```

Comment: No...there is no CSS method for determining whether a line has or will wrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing this, but it only works because there is an interpreter between the original text and the HTML. Originally, the interpreter placed <pre> before the text and </pre> after the text. I altered it to place <pre> before each line and \n</pre> at the end of each line (the \n is a newline character to force a line break). Then, I make a 1 pixel gray image called gray.png. With that, I did:

```
pre {
  white-space:pre-wrap;
  padding-left:1em;
  text-indent:-1em;
  background-image:url(gray.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:0px 1.5em;
  background-size:1em 100em;
}
```

Now, for a normal line, the padding and text-indent cancel each other out. The text shows up in the normal position. When the text wraps, the text is indented due to the padding. Also, the background image shows up on the left. It is 100em tall, so it will span many lines. I couldn't use repeat-y because that repeats both directions, up and down. The end result looks nice to me.

Comment: `background-position` does not take absolute positioning units like pixels or ems, the only allowed values are among `top`, `bottom`, `center`, `right`, `left`, etc.

Comment: @galaxy background-position can take the settings you mentioned as well as x% y%, or xpos ypos, or initial, or inherit. It is well documented.

Comment: thanks - I looked up the definition of that property, you are correct.  I actually spent some time playing with the idea you presented and came up with quite a decent looking indicator: https://dmitry.khlebnikov.net/2020/05/10/wrap-indicator-in-pre-blocks/#bonus-round (the difference is that I used a unicode character as the background) and clipping.

Comment: Actually, my solution is more universal since it follows the semantic web and I am not breaking `<pre>` block into a tag per line, but use `<div>` for line marking, anyway - thanks for the idea, @kainaw!

Answer (score 3):

Just tried to be imaginative: if you have a maximum number of lines in your code snippets you may play with a pseudoelement:

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRRyJa)

---

**Markup**

```
<pre>&lt;html>
   &lt;body>
       Hello World
   &lt;/body>
&lt;/html&gt;
</pre>
```

**CSS**

```
pre {
  background: yellowgreen;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 30px;
  border: 15px yellowgreen solid;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1.25em;
  text-indent: -1.25em;
}

pre:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  color: #424242;
  content: "\A\2424\A\2424\A\2424..." /* Ad libitum */
}
```

As a newline symbol I've used the [unicode U+2424](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2424/index.htm) (`␤`) `SYMBOL FOR NEWLINE` but of course you can pick another one from the unicode table

The idea is to use the `pre:before` appearing from the second line (content starts with a newline) thanks to the `padding-left` applied (the first line has a negative `text-indent`).

This works until you define a number of pairs `\A\2424` inside the `content` property at least equal to the maximum number of LOC.

---

**Final result**

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure I'm reading this correctly... You are placing a dot before every line, but outdenting the first line and setting overflow to hidden so the dot falls outside and isn't shown in the first line. Correct?

Comment: @kainaw  not exactly: the symbol appears from the second line because the content property starts with a newline `\A`

Comment: Thanks. This works, but it isn't how I ended up doing it. First, I had the interpreter turn each line of of text into a unique <pre>...</pre> line instead of just having <pre> at the top and </pre> at the end. Then, I added a the write-space wrap. Then, I added padding to the left of 1em and indent of -1em. Finally, I added a background image of a gray box that is 1em wide, 100em tall, and set 0px left and 1.5em top.

Answer (score 1):

As far as pure CSS goes, you can look into [`::first-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line) to colour your text differently (or any other font-related properties), but this only works on the first line, which in my proposal, would mean you'd have to make a new `<pre>` block for each line of content, which isn't very flexible of a solution.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

pre {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  background: aliceblue;
  
  /* Below styles the second+ line */
  color: red;
}

pre::first-line { /* Styles the first line */
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<pre>
&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;Hello World&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
</pre>
```